# In R: Get multiple barplots from a single output

Tags: r

I have a data frame (100 x 4). The first column is a set of "bins" 0-100, the remaining columns are the counts for each variable of events within each bin (0 to the maximum number of events).

What I'm trying to do is to plot each of the three columns of data (2:4), alongside each other. Because the counts in each of the bins for each of the data sets is close to identical, the data are overlapped in the histogram/barplots I've created, despite my use of beside=true, and position = dodge.

I've set the first column as both numeric and character, but the results are identical- the bars are overlayed on top of each other. (semi-transparent density plots don't work because I want counts not the distribution densities).

The attached code, based on both R and other documentation produced the attached chart.

```
barplot(BinCntDF$preT,main=NewMain_Trigger, plot=TRUE,
    xlab="sample frequency interval counts (0-100 msec bins)", 
    names.arg=BinCntDF$dT, las=0,
    ylab="bin counts", axes=TRUE, xlim=c(0,100), 
    ylim=c(0,1000), col="red") 
 geom_bar(position="dodge")
 barplot(BinCntDF$postT, beside=TRUE, add=TRUE)
 geom_bar()
```

The goal is to be able to compare the two (or more) data sets side by side on the same axes, without either overlapping the other(s).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have confused `barplot` with `ggplot2`. `ggplot2` is a library where the function `geom_bar` comes from and isn't compatible with `barplot` which comes with Base R.

Simply compare `?barplot` and `?geom_bar`, and you will see that `geom_bar` is from the `ggplot2` library. To achieve what you're after I have used the `ggplot2` library and `reshape2`.

**Step 1**

Based on your description, I have assumed that your data looks roughly like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, 
                 c1 = sample(0:100, replace=TRUE, size=10),
                 c2 = sample(0:50, replace=TRUE, size=10),
                 c3 = sample(0:70, replace=TRUE, size=10))
```

To plot it using `ggplot2` you first have to transform the data to a long format instead of a wide format. You can do this using `melt` function from `reshape2`.

```
library(reshape2)
a <- melt(df, id=c("x"))
```

The output would look something like this

```
> head(a)
  x variable value
1 1       c1    62
2 2       c1    47
3 3       c1    20
4 4       c1    64
5 5       c1     4
6 6       c1    52
```

**Step 2**

There are plenty of tutorials online to what `ggplot2` does and the arguments. I would recommend you Google, or search through the many threads in SO to understand.

```
ggplot(a, aes(x=x, y=value, group=variable, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

Which gives you the output:

[image]

In a nutshell:

- `group` groups the variables of interest
- `stat=identity` ensures that no additional aggregations are made on your data

Answer (score 0):

With that many bins (100) and groups (3) the plot will look messy, but try this:

```
set.seed(123)
myDF <- data.frame(bins=1:100, x=sample(1:100, replace=T), y=sample(1:100, replace=T), z=sample(1:100, replace=T))
myDF.m <- melt(myDF, id.vars='bins')
ggplot(myDF.m, aes(x=bins, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

[image: Barplot 1]

You could also try plotting w/ facets:

```
ggplot(myDF.m, aes(x=bins, y=value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

[image: Barplot 2]

Comment: Thank you all. From your comments i agree that  I've incorrectly used / combined ggplot and geom_bar with my data. Both the facet and ggplot/geom_bar as you've written would work for my data. I'll modify the code and data structure, plot the data both ways and see which visualization works best and post the results- graphs if possible or a simple thumbs up/down if not.